# function with an istream& parameter C++

Tags: c++, function, ifstream

I would like my program to read a file using the function "readFile" below. I am trying to find out how to call a function with an istream& parameter. The goal of the function is to read the file by receiving the file's name as parameter.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool readFile(std::istream& fileName); //error 1 this line

int main(void)
{   
    string fileName;

    cout << "Enter the file name: ";
    cin >> fileName;

    readFile(fileName); //error 2 this line


}

bool readFile(std::istream& fileName)
{
    ifstream file(fileName, ios::in); //error 3 this line
    return true;
}
```

The three errors I get:

error 1 : in passing argument 1 of 'bool readFile(std::istream&)

error 2 : invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::istream& {aka std::basic_istream&}' from expression of type 'std::string {aka std::basic_string}

error 3 : invalid user-defined conversion from 'std::istream {aka std::basic_istream}' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]

Is there anyway I can fix it? The parameter of the function really has to remain "std::istream& fileName".

Thanks for helping.

Comment: The *caller* of `readFile` is pretty important here. Is the `std::istream&` parameter passed in *already opened* on the file? If so, you needn't open it again, I would think.

Comment: I am just trying to build the code, not trying to make it work with an example.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to the `std::ifstream` constructor should be a string. You're trying to pass it a `std::istream`. Maybe the `std::istream` contains the name of the file you want to read, in which case you want to extract the name into a `std::string` first. Something like this might work:

```
std::string fileName;
name >> fileName;
std::ifstream file(fileName, ios::in);
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph this is exactly what I am trying to do, but unfortunately your suggestion doesn't work.

Comment: @Alex What doesn't work about it? You need to explain what exactly is being passed to the function as the `name` argument.

Comment: I am just trying to build it with no error. I am not even calling it with something. This is part of the console error message:

**** Internal Builder is used for build               ****
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -ovalidationFormat.o ..\validationFormat.cpp
..\validationFormat.cpp: In function 'bool readFile(std::istream&)':
..\validationFormat.cpp:168:36: error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(std::string&, const openmode&)'
  ifstream fichier(fileName, ios::in);

Comment: @Alex But you have to tell us the error for us to be able to fix it. What's the error?

Comment: I also get this at the bottom of the error message: note:   no known conversion for implicit 'this' parameter from 'void*' to 'const char*'

Comment: @Alex That error has nothing to do with the code you have here. That's a problem for another SO question.